# How do I use glCreateBuffers() over glGenBuffers()?

Tags: c++, opengl

When I was using opengl 3.3, functions such as, **glGenBuffers()** and **glBufferData()** Worked Just fine, but now that I am using 4.3 I wish to use the more updated versions of those functions such as **glCreateBuffers()** and:

**glNamedBufferStorage(), glVertexArrayVertexBuffer, glVertexArrayAttribFormat(), glVertexArrayAttribBinding(), glEnableVertexArrayAttrib().**

When I implement them in the program I simply get Unhanded expression errors. 
The book I am learning from (Superbible) no longer teaches the **GenBuffer()** Method so I need to make these work. 
Thank You!

Comment: Could you post some code that generates that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> using 4.3
>
> glCreateBuffers

[glCreateBuffers](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glCreateBuffers.xhtml) is part of OpenGL 4.5 (and ARB_direct_state_access).

Comment: And this requires my Graphics card to be running a opengl 4.5 driver?

Comment: Or [ARB_direct_state_access](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/direct_state_access.txt).

Comment: How do I add it to my program? sorry, slightly new at this.

Comment: Hi @Nicol I really dont want to post a new question on extensions, if  you could just give me a quick explanation on how to implement  ARB_direct_state_access that would be great, Ive been looking everywhere.

Comment: Calling OpenGL extension functions, *any extension*, is basic OpenGL stuff. If you've looked everywhere for it and can't find it, then you're not looking very hard.

Comment: Like I said, Im new, maybe I dont know exactly what to search for or what I tried didnt work, Thats why Im asking you

Comment: @Cole-Peterson: You could have searched for "OpenGL Extension". Any of the first three hits on Google would have helped. They wouldn't have provided code you could copy-and-paste into your program though.